# Search result is shown on Google search but not when searching on the site

Tags: google-search, search-engines

I was searching the site https://www.hausarztberlin.de/hausarzt/ for "Knorpelschützende Substanzen" which led to following google search result page:
https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.hausarztberlin.de%2Fhausarzt%2F+knorpelsch%C3%BCtzende+substanzen&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.hausarztberlin.de%2Fhausarzt%2F+knorpelsch%C3%BCtzende+substanzen&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.10911j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

see:
[image]

On this page there was one search result on the page. However, when opening the page, and using CTRl+F in Chrome, there was no search result. I assume that the text is in a box which was not opened so that Chrome does not find it. Is there an easy way to expand all sections or to know in which section I can find the text?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The text seems to appear under the "Privatärztliche Leistungen" link near the bottom (it was available via "Find" once the link was "expanded"). That said, offhand, I am not certain there is an easy way expand all the links other than by clicking on them. You could also look at the page source code (like Google likely did), but this may not work for all sites (and may not be as human-reader friendly).

Comment: One possible cause is that Google has not indexed the site lately, and you're looking at a cached version. Try looking at Google's cache, or use the Wayback Machine. See also https://cachedview.com/

Comment: @Anaksunaman what do you mean with "expanding" the link? Do you simply mean opening the website and looking through all sections by expanding them?

Comment: @datasciencelearner *"Do you mean opening the website and looking through all sections by expanding them?"* - Yes, that is what I was referring to. That web page effectively hides blocks of text in the rendered page from the browser (including "Find") until a given link is "expanded" by clicking on it. I tried "Find" initially (which failed) and then simply went through all the sections, clicking on them to load the accompanying hidden text ("expand" them) and tried "Find" again (which worked).

Comment: As others said, the website hides the information, which is bad IMHO. But anyway, the site should offer a site search so that you can find matching snippets in this site itself. A cognitive site search engine for German ("bedeutungsorientierte Suchmaschine" in German) would be best for such sites. (I can provide more advice if anyone is interested.)